# Generating simple plots within LaTeX

Tags: latex

I want to draw a couple of simple bar plots to include in a LaTeX document.

For some reason (unless im missing something), there doesn't appear to be a simple way to generate bar plots in LaTeX.

I could of course generate them in Excel and save them as PDF, but I'd rather have the flexibility of doing them dynamically in LaTeX.

I looked into TikZ, but it seems nobody on the interwebs is using it for a measly barchart (which is what I need it for), and the code below generates a barplot without any axis:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[ycomb, color=gray,line width=0.5cm] 
        plot coordinates{(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What do you use?  Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Just FYI, there is actuall a LaTeX StackExchange site at http://tex.stackexchange.com/. You'll most likely get more answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you want [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots): this is built on top of Tikz as a proper plot-drawing interface.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, you're spot on. This is perfect.

Comment: No problem: I love `pgfplots`!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you're familiar with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), that can generate bar plots. There is a ["TikZ terminal"](http://peter.affenbande.org/gnuplot/) (something that outputs TikZ-code) for gnuplot, however, as far as i know, you have to compile it yourself in order to get it working.

I think there's also another "LaTeX terminal" generating pstricks (?) code or something similar.

Comment: Sweet - this looks like what I think I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can I point you towards [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote_(vector_graphics_language)), [Gallery](http://www.piprime.fr/asymptote/)). You can make professional looking graphs offline from LaTex processing, but being LaTeX aware. It is a full blown C-ish language for vector graphics and function graphing. The output eventually is encapsulated postscript (eps) which can be displayed directly into LaTeX documents.